# How can I reject access to server for POST requests with long content lengths

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, httpd, wordpress

I have a problem with our server (CentOS 6) where we are getting repeated requests to access wp-login.php on a URL that doesn't exist, although Wordpress will try and redirect.

We get a number of these in quick succession such that it sends Apache into a spin and consumes all the memory on the box. The only way to resolve at present is to restart the server.

Looking at the logs we can see the following repeated:

```
"POST /products/productname/wp-login.php HTTP/1.0" 200 6761
```

This clearly isn't correct as it is POST and of a very long length.

What is the best way to trap and exclude these types of request?

Answer (score 1):

You want your Apache to not even redirect that junk in the first place.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteRule ^/wp-login.php - [R=401]
```

Deny all with 401, assuming `/wp-login.php` is the URI in question.

Comment: Put that in .htaccess in the root and /wp-admin but it doesn't seem to have made any difference as are still seeing those requests in the access logs and they are still killing the server. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yeah, that was off the top of my head - try `RewriteRule /wp-login.php - [F]`. `F` flag for "forbidden", also don't anchor at the URI start because there is a leading path in your examples. I'd also recommend putting it into your vhost or a `conf.d` snippet, not `.htaccess`.